# Make a .reg file to add shortcuts in right click menu

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu, vlc, 7zip

My problem is about manipulation about Windows Registry (using windows 7).

Let's see the following screenshot :

[image]

I right cliked on an AVI file, and I have some options. First one I want to talk : "Lire avec VLC" (english : "Read with VLC").

The VLC software adds, somewhere in the registry, that AVI files are associated with this option.

You can also see "7-zip" options, with an arrow for suboptions (Add to archive, Compress with...)
7-zip added this to ALL type of files.

I would like to add my own shortcuts in the right click/context menu. How can I add an option like VLC, specific to a file type? How can I add a global options like 7-zip, and how to add submenu options like 7-zip does?

I'd like to write a .reg file that can do it.

Comment: 7-Zip adds context menu commands via providing a shell extension - a DLL which integrates into shell through registry and then provides menu items. It is not just registry entries (even though registry only commands are also possible).

Answer (score 6):

You can add an option for a specific file type like this

```lisp
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.avi reveals WMP11.AssocFile.AVI
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WMP11.AssocFile.AVI\shell\hello\command]
@="hello.exe"
```

You can add a cascading menu when you right click the background

```lisp
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\hello]
"SubCommands"="world"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\world]
@="world"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\world\command]
@="world.exe"
```

Note: you might need to use full paths, if your programs are not on the PATH.

[image: cascading menu]

[Your Menu: Add Programs In Right-Click Context Menu](http://addictivetips.com/windows-tips/your-menu-add-programs-applications-link-shortcuts-in-right-click-context-menu)

Comment: Remember to escape reverse slashes if you need to specify an absolute path in Windows for the commands.